# Check whether two strings have same contents regardless of word order

Tags: java

I have two strings, eg:

`Long sentences may be used for several reasons: To develop tension. While a short sentence is the ultimate sign of the tension, long sentences could be used to develop this tension to a point of culmination. To give vivid descriptions.`

`Long sentences may be used for several reasons: To develop tension. While a short sentence is the sign ultimate of the tension, long sentences could be used to develop this tension to a point of culmination. To give vivid descriptions.`

In the second string, the word **ultimate** has changed its position.

`if(string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2))` returns **False** but I want the result to be **True** since the contents of the strings are same (even though the order is not).

Comment: What is it exactly what you want? Those strings are not equal. Do you want to know whether they contain the same words, regardless of the order, or something else?

Comment: those Strings don't have the same content, so equals is returning the correct result. what you can do to check if it contains is to split it in words, and check  word by word if the nr of occurrences is the same, if the number of words is the same, ..

Comment: If you just want to extract the repeated words between the two, you can try to use `regex` to extract the value, and then analyze whether most of them are the same according to the results

Comment: I want my result to be true @kutschkem, coz even through order is changed the content are same

Comment: @Stultuske is there any other way coz I have a longer string than this, it consist of 30 to 40 sentences and it will take more time to check and return the result

Comment: @lan I thought of regex too but how to create pattern for it and check the contents, and if there are duplicate words it will come as true

Comment: I think you can collect the words in ``Set`` so that every word is captured only once and then compare those ``Set``. If they are equal, you can assume the strings contain same words

Comment: @pratap better use an hashmap, using the word as a key, and counting the occurrences in the value, so if you have 2 phrases with duplicated words, you can still match 'em

Comment: @KaranRaj Mainly I don't know what the result you want is. If you want to simply judge the similarity of two sentences, there are many ways to do it. For example, split each word, determine the number of repeated words in the two sentences, and then Calculate the number of words in the sentence being compared to get the percentage. This can even be done in a few loops. Of course, there must be errors in these methods, so in the end it depends on what kind of result you want

Comment: "even through order is changed the content are same" - that's not generally true of statements though. "Paris is the capital of France" is not the same statement as "France is the capital of Paris" is it? (Or "One plus one equals two" isn't the same as "One plus two equals one".)

Comment: @BigMike yes, thats good suggestion.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes but for my case is different, it is not about the meaning of the sentence it is only the contents, I used that statement for example

Comment: Have hopefully clarified the question statement

Comment: @tucuxi yes Thanks for that, this my first question, I will increase my question framing skills :)

Comment: Okay, I think that would be clearer if you used examples that weren't even statements. Statements *do* have meaning, and the use of them in the examples suggests that the meaning is relevant. My next question would be whether you'd want "abc abc def" and "def abc" to be equivalent. They have the same words ("abc" and "def") but not only is the *order* different, but the *counts* of the words are different. What about capitalization - if you *are* using actual sentences would "The cat is a mammal" and "A cat is the mammal" be considered equivalent? (The question should contain a clear spec.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count the occurences of every word in each `String` and compare the results :

```java
String phrase = "Long sentences may be used for several reasons: To develop tension. While a short sentence is the ultimate sign of the tension, long sentences could be used to develop this tension to a point of culmination. To give vivid descriptions.";
String phrase2 = "Long sentences may be used for several reasons: To develop tension. While a short sentence is the sign ultimate of the tension, long sentences could be used to develop this tension to a point of culmination. To give vivid descriptions.";
      
Map<String,Long> wordCount = Arrays.stream(phrase.toLowerCase().split("\\W+"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        
Map<String,Long> wordCount2 = Arrays.stream(phrase2.toLowerCase().split("\\W+"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        
System.out.println(wordCount.equals(wordCount2));
```

- The first step is to apply [`toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) to your `String`. Remove this step if you want your comparison to be case sensitive.

  - `"Hello world"` => `"hello world"`
- Then you [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) the `String` around the matches of the following regex : `\W+` to obtain an array. This regex matches one or more non-word character.

  - `"hello world"` => `["hello", "world"]`
- You call [`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D)) on this array to get a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html).
- You collect the elements of the `Stream` using [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) to associate every word with its number of occurences. [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) is a function that returns its input.

  - `{"hello": 1, "world": 1}`

Comment: Thanks Tom, can you explain to me how it works

Comment: @KaranRaj I added some details.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate version of [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70798356/15472). It should be faster for small-ish strings, since it does not spend time & memory to count words, but Tom's version will be better for very long strings (which will likely contain many duplicate words), as comparing word-counts should be much faster than comparing the full text, once the full text enters into the million-word or so range.

```
public static boolean equalWordsAndCountsIgnoringOrder(String s1, String s2) {
    String[] w1 = s1.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
    String[] w2 = s2.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
    Arrays.sort(w1);
    Arrays.sort(w2);
    return Arrays.equals(w1, w2);
}
```

We first convert the strings into arrays with their words lower-cased. Then we sort those arrays. Finally, we test that the exact same words appear in the exact same places.

Usage:

```
System.out.println(equalWordsAndCountsIgnoringOrder(phrase, phrase2));
```